# Как сделать парсинг страницы

Tags: c#

Начинаю осваиваться в парсинге страниц. Хочу достать данные из таблицы в википедии https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8 использую AngleSharp.

Написал следующий код, но он никаких данных не выводит. Пока идея такая, вытащить всё тело таблицы tbody. Написал следующий код:

```
        var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader();

        var htmlDocument = await BrowsingContext.New(config).OpenAsync(addess);

        var items = htmlDocument.QuerySelectorAll("table standard sortable jquery-tablesorter > tbody");

        foreach (var i in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i.TextContent);
        }
```

До этого строка items была следующий:

```
var items = htmlDocument.QuerySelectorAll("tbody").Where("standard sortable jquery-tablesorter");
```

Но я получал ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Рекомендую ознакомиться: [тыц](https://habr.com/ru/post/579336/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> "table standard sortable jquery-tablesorter > tbody"
> ```

```
"table.standard.sortable.jquery-tablesorter > tbody"
```

Comment: Там получается на вход приходит не table.standard.sortable.jquery-tablesorter, а table.standard.sortable > tbody . А так да ва ответ поможет) Спасибо